# Ошибка при миграции python django

Tags: python, django, foreign-key

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
Появляется такая ошибка при миграции.

```
status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

Код, который, похоже, вызывает проблемы. Как исправить?

Comment: Для начала можно попробовать гуглить. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44026807/11214129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить позиционный аргумент [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

***Пример:***

```py
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Данный аргумент отвечает за то, что произойдёт при удалении связанного объекта.

Значение `CASCADE` говорит, что запись, которая ссылается на удалённый объект, тоже должна быть удалена.